# Json field and array to csv using python

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

Need to generate a csv file from json field and array.

json file contains one field and an array. I need to create a csv file with one col as field and another has values retrieved from an array.

Input:

```
{
  "Emp": {
    "EmpID": SE451,
    "EMpName": "Vincent",
    "Leaves": [
      {
        "leave": 2
      },
      {
        "leave": 1
      }
    ]
}
```

The **expected** csv should be like this,

| E_name | E_leaves |
| --- | --- |
| Vincent | 2 |
|  | 1 |

For this I have tried with below code and it is not working as expected.

```
Fl_content = []
dat_content=[]
emp_ids = ('E_name','E_Leaves')
hdr = ','.join(emp_ids)
for ar in json_data['Emp']['Leaves']:
  Fl_content.append(str(ar['leave']))

leave_data = '\n'.join(Fl_content)
leave_with_header = json_data['Emp']['EmpName'], leave_data
dat3 = ','.join(leave_with_header)
#print(dat3)
hdr+'\n'+dat3
```

the csv string I got is `E_name,E_leaves\nVinent,2\n1`

and my csv file looks like this (it is not expected),

| E_name | E_leaves |
| --- | --- |
| Vincent | 2 |
| 1 |  |

Note: I am working with cloud functions to upload the csv in GCS bucket.
hence I would like to achieve this using csv string concept.

Help me to achieve expected one as stated above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding `E_name` field you need to fill it with empty string after first row.
Also it's better to render rows first and compose csv string by iterating them.

```
def render_csv_str(data: dict) -> str:
    headers = ['E_name', 'E_leaves']
    rows = []
    index = 0
    for ar in data['Emp']['Leaves']:
        if index == 0:
            rows.append((data['Emp']['EmpName'], f"{ar['leave']}"))
        else:
            rows.append(('', f"{ar['leave']}"))

        index = index + 1

    csv_str = ','.join(headers)
    csv_str += '\n'
    for row in rows:
        csv_str += ','.join(row)
        csv_str += '\n'

    return csv_str


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_dict = {
        "Emp": {
            "EmpID": 'SE451',
            "EmpName": "Vincent",
            "Leaves": [{
                "leave": 2
            },
            {
                "leave": 1
            }]
        }
    }

    print(render_csv_str(test_dict))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work:

```
employee_name = json_data['Emp']['EmpName']

leave_values = [str(leave['leave']) for leave in json_data['Emp']['Leaves']]

csv_data = []
csv_data.append("E_name,E_leaves")  # Header
for leave in leave_values:
    csv_data.append(f"{employee_name},{leave}")

csv_content = '\n'.join(csv_data)

print(csv_content)
```

Your code was not working as expected mainly due to how you structured the `CSV` data.

You added leave values directly to `leave_data` as a single string, separated by line breaks. This would create a single cell in the `CSV` for `E_leaves` with all the values in one row and you would want each leave value to be in a separate row.

Also, you weren't adding the employee's name (`E_name`) to each leave line.

In the original code, you concatenated all the `CSV` lines into a single string, but did nothing with the resulting string. You were printing the header and the resulting string separately, but you didn't assign or save the result anywhere.

We resolved these issues by adding each leave line separately with the corresponding employee name and ensuring the header was included in the `CSV`.

Comment: Thanks @Giba, your explanation and the solution is helpful to me.